# Remove Style attribute on div tag

Tags: jquery, css

Can any one tell me, how do I remove style attribute from this below div?

```
<div class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv" style="width: 1085px;">
```

I have tried the below, but,it does not remove it.

```
$('.ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv').removeAttr('style')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `dot` or `comma` to join the classes in selector

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ndASG/)**

```
$('.ui-state-default.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').removeAttr('style')
```

Comment: Just goes to show - in jQuery, always, always, always ensure the stack contains the elements you think it does before wondering why things don't work.

Comment: why dot? not comma? like this:$('.ui-state-default, .ui-jqgrid-hdiv').removeAttr('style'); will this example work?

Comment: Thanks @barlasapaydin, I did not know about comma

Comment: comma works too, http://jsfiddle.net/ndASG/1/ it defines/separates different classes.

Comment: I checked that after you first comment Thanks again :)

Comment: If you use comma, it will match elements that have any of the those two classes. If you use a dot (and **no spaces**) it will match elements that have **both** classes. The OP's code failed because it looked for a `ui-jqgrid-hdiv` that is child of `ui-state-default`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this might be of help?..

```
var width = $(window).width(); //Just assuming screen width

$('#gridId').setGriWidth(width);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your selector.

```
$('.ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv').removeAttr('style')
```

needs to be

```
$('.ui-state-default.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').removeAttr('style')
```